# "You cannon proceed with such operation, your reCaptcha reputation is too low" - what does that mean, as if explaining to a 5 year old? :)

Tags: magento, recaptcha

a user gets this message when trying to login to a store (magento): "You cannon proceed with such operation, your reCaptcha reputation is too low" - how do you fix that? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be that reCaptcha doesn't always work properly in Firefox.  I often have a problem logging in to sites that have reCaptcha when using Firefox.  If I switch to Chrome it's fine.